# How to fix a feature-envy of project based on Java?

Tags: java, refactoring, feature-envy

After I used "inFusion Hydrogen" to analyze my project, it's pretty easy to figure out myQuestionFun() is causing feature-envy.

```
public abstract class Father{
    protected DataModel dataModel;
    public abstract void myQuestionFun();
}
public class Child extends Father{

    public DataModel<TableInfo> tableList = new DataModel<TableInfo>;
    public DataModel<TableInfo> getTableList(){
        return this.tableList;
    }

    @Override
    public DataModel<Report> getDataModel(){
        return this.dataModel;
    }

    @Override
    public void myQuestionFun(){
        List<TableInfo> tabList = new ArrayList<TableInfo>();
        for (int i=0; dataModel.getDataList().size(); i++) {
            Report rep = (Report)dataModel.getDataList.get(i);
            TableInfo tabInfo = new TableInfo();
            tabInfo.setId(rep.getId());
            tabInfo.setName(rep.getName());
            tabList.add(tabInfo);
        }
        tableList.setPage(dataModel.getPage());
        tableList.setSorter(dataModel.getSorter());
   }
}
```

The question is, what's the best way to fix it?
Because myQuestionFun() is a function of the abstract method of the parent class, I can't move it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract following code as a method from Child into the Father:

```
protected List<TableInfo> getTabList() {
    final List<TableInfo> tabList = new ArrayList<TableInfo>();
    for (int i=0; dataModel.getDataList().size(); i++) {
            Report rep = (Report) dataModel.getDataList.get(i);
            TableInfo tabInfo = new TableInfo();
            tabInfo.setId(rep.getId());
            tabInfo.setName(rep.getName());
            tabList.add(tabInfo);
    }
    return tabList;
}
```

Move following method to Father, if it is ALWAYS supposed to return this.dataModel :

```
public DataModel<Report> getDataModel(){
   return this.dataModel;
}
```

Comment: I accept your advice about moving getDateModel() method to Father. but I don't know how to extract a method from child into father. many subclasses extends to the Father class in my project, the implementation of myQuestionFun() method  for each subclass is different.

Comment: I suggested moving getDataModel() to father if it always return this.dataModel. If that is not the case then either leave it there or move a generic implementation to Father and override it in only those children where needed.

Comment: I think my 'feature-envy' problem is that myQuestionFun() uses the external data---rep.getId().  but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I think you can still extract getTabList() into Father and override it in the children where different implementation is needed. The method myQuestionFun() will call getTabList(). It would be great if you could please share two examples of children to express your use-case better.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `dataModel` field form `Father` and change in into an interface.